# Form post script not working with new fields

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP/jQuery script that loads form data without refreshing the page.  It works perfect except when I attempt to add a new field.  Perhaps JQUERY will only allow certain fields?

The below code works great except for the 'text' form field.  The text form field is the the custom field that I attempted to add to the default script.  All fields post data except for the default field.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Submit Form without Page Refresh - PHP/jQuery - TecAdmin.net</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/submit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post">
   Name:    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />
   Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
   Phone No:<input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" /><br />
   Gender:  <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male">Male
            <input name="gender" type="radio" value="female">Female<br />
   Text:     <input name="text" id="text" type="text" /><br />
 
   <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 <br/>
   Your data will display below... <br />
   ==============================<br />
 <div id="results">
    <!-- All data will display here  -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript - JQUERY**

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var gender = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { name: name, email: email, phone: phone, gender: gender, text: text },
       function(data) {
         $('#results').html(data);
         $('#myForm')[0].reset();
       });
}
```

**PHP (submit.php)**

```
<?php

  echo $_POST['name'] . "<br />";
  echo $_POST['email'] . "<br />";
  echo $_POST['phone'] . "<br />";
  echo $_POST['gender'] . "<br />";
  echo $_POST['text'] . "<br />";
  echo "==============================<br />";
  echo "All Data Submitted Successfully!";

?>
```

Comment: As an experiment, I would try changing the name of the variable in javascript from `text` to `_text`. So `var _text` and refer to that new variable in the data: `gender: gender, text: _text`. Just to see if it that fixes the problem.

Comment: imvain2 - Thanks for the feedback.  I have tried, with the _text, and that broke everything.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I tried the code and it worked as expected.

Comment: El_Vanja - You're able to get the "text" field to work?    hmmm...

Comment: Worked for me as well, same result as El_Vanja

Comment: I literally copied the code from your question. Side note: it is redundant to define the object like this: `{ name: name, email: email...`, when key and variable have the same values, you can just add the variables: `{ name, email...`.

Comment: El_Vanja - Thanks for the feed back.  I am not sure why the Text field won't post an all of the other fields post fine.  The only difference is the other fields were there by default, and I manually added the text field.  But if it's working for you, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Paul T.  - To make sure I follow correctly, all 5 field are working for you as well??

Comment: @EL_Vanja you're right about the key:variables, I just added the variables and it still works as before.  Still not getting the new field to work though.  _text, desc, description, nothing is working for me.  Strange.  I wonder if it's my version of jquery.

Comment: You include `jquery-latest.js` from their CDN and I've copied that line too. So it shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Hmmm... I get Notice: Undefined index: description in ... etc.   Other other fields are working.  What could possibly be my issue?

Comment: Can you post the full notice (with file and line)?

Comment: - Notice: Undefined index: text in /home/homdir/website.org/refresh/submit.php on line 11 -

Comment: Is there anything else in `submit.php` you're not showing? Because in your snippet, line 11 is the closing tag.

Comment: @El_Vanja - To answer your question.  There is code to check for errors that I put at the beginning of the  script.  - Below is the full code.  line 11 pints to the 'text' field.  - without the extra code the full is is as my next post.

Comment: @El_Vanja and all others who spent time on this.  Thank you for your help.  I figured it out.  It was a caching issue.  See the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. There is no issue with the original script.  It was the browser caching old values.   After completely, clearing out the cache in the Edge and Chrome (the browsers in which I used to test the script) - I got all fields to work.

After adding the new field the old cached js, or post values still carried over, and didn't allow the new entry.

It worked fine on browsers who used it for the first time, as there were no data cached.

To prevent caching from happening after adding/removing fields... add the following cache clearing line to the beginning of the submit.php.

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```